# Create Dictionary out of constants class in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class containing several string constants:

```
 public class TemplateConstants
  {
    public static readonly string Type = "«Type»";
    public static readonly string Purpose = "«Purpose»";
    public static readonly string FirstName = "«FirstName»";
 ....
 }
```

Each of these represents a "placeholder". I have a HTML document containing various placeholders. In my Web API controller (C#) I am replacing these placeholders one at a time:

```
 string doc = string.Empty;
 string htmltest = System.IO.File.ReadAllText     
(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\Templates\Template.html"));
doc = htmltest.Replace(TemplateConstants.ApplicationType, applicationType);
        doc = doc.Replace(TemplateConstants.LoanPurpose, loanType);
        doc = doc.Replace(ApplicationDocTemplateConstants.BorrowerFirstName, FirstName);
.....
```

Is there a way to use a Dictionary here instead so that I can loop through the file somehow and do substitutions based on the dictionary (rather than having to do each substitution one at a time)?

Comment: That's not how you do a string constant in C# - you should replace "static readonly" with "const." A readonly string is **not** the same as a const string - the difference is that readonly is a runtime constant and const is a compile-time const, so if you use const the compiler can do the substitution statically.

Comment: nakisa, if possible, dont go to the dictionary solution. try using a frmaework that would do the hard work.
see the Razor answer below. it would save u a lot of time.

Comment: I agree with Amir. What you're trying to do is HTML Templating, and there are entire libraries written for that specific purpose. They solve problems you haven't even considered yet (like what happens if someone injects malicious HTML and JavaScript into the First Name field of your application?)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior it would be the internal application, so not much worried for security. The other thing is it is Web API so the answer for Rasor view will not work

Comment: @nakisa: Sure it'll work. The example Amir provided is a console app, not MVC. The Razor engine can be invoked as a general HTML templating engine: it doesn't have to be part of an HTTP request or anything. And security isn't the only issue that an engine like Razor addresses--it's just one example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use Razor view engine programically like in this example:
http://razorengine.codeplex.com/ 
(nuget RazorEngine)

```
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Templating; // For extension methods.

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string template = "Hello @Model.Types, welcome to RazorEngine!";
        var result =
            Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, new TemplateConstants());

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}

public class TemplateConstants
{
    public readonly string Types = "Some type";
    public readonly string Purpose = "«Purpose»";
    public readonly string FirstName = "«FirstName»";

}
```

of course your template should be in Razor syntax
like :

```
<html>
...
<div>@Model.Purpose</div>
<div>@Model.FirstName</div>
...
</html>
```

see also :https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

Answer (score 0):

I converted your static strings to constants, then added a method that converts the constants into a dictionary.

```
public class TemplateConstants
{
    public const string Type = "«Type»";
    public const string Purpose = "«Purpose»";
    public const string FirstName = "«FirstName»";

    private static readonly Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>> ConstantsDictionary =
        new Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>>(CreateDictionary);

    public static Dictionary<string, string> AsDictionary()
    {
        return ConstantsDictionary.Value;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, string> CreateDictionary()
    {
        var fields = typeof(TemplateConstants)
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        var constants = fields.Where(f => f.IsLiteral && !f.IsInitOnly).ToList();
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var instance = new TemplateConstants();

        // Up to you if you want to filter the constants further to only include those
        // with string values.
        constants.ForEach(constant => result.Add(constant.Name, constant.GetValue(instance).ToString()));
        return result;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestTemplateConstants
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDictionary()
    {
        var dictionary = TemplateConstants.AsDictionary();
        Assert.AreEqual(dictionary["Type"],TemplateConstants.Type);
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW - I agree with the other comments that using a dictionary probably isn't the way to do what you're trying to do. I'm just answering the question literally. There are scenarios where doing this could be useful.